# Can anyone tell me why my alert not working

Tags: javascript

```js
var tweet = prompt("type your tweet here:");
var tweetcount = tweet.lenght
alert("you have writed " + tweetcount + " character, " + "you have " (180 - tweetcount) + "character");
```

I'm trying to learn how character count work.

Comment: You are missing a `+` between `"you have "` and `(180 - tweetcount)`.

Comment: Also: typo - `lenght` should be `length`.

Comment: and http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as @ivar and @andy mentioned above
You are missing a + between "you have " and (180 - tweetcount)
and .lenght should be .length

```js
var tweet = prompt("type your tweet here:");
var tweetcount = tweet.length 
alert("you have writed " + tweetcount + " character, " + "you have " + (180 - tweetcount) + " character");
```